# Confetti function doesn't fall when called

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

```
    func confettiStart() {

        confettiView.frame = self.view.bounds

        self.view.addSubview(confettiView)
        
        confettiView.startAnimating()
        print("TEST")
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        

        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
    }

    @objc func handleTap() {
        confettiView.stopAnimating()
        confettiView.removeFromSuperview()
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = true
        winMusic?.stop()
        
        
    }
```

I am calling this confetti function from checkwinner function below, and the confetti falls when it should and stops falling when a tap is registered on the screen

```
    func checkWinner() {
        
            
              nullButtons()
          backgroundMusic?.stop()
             
              restartLabel.isHidden = false
              restartLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
              timerLabel.isHidden = true
              timeLeft = 136
                
              playWinMusic()
        
              confettiStart()
            //print("TEST")
        }
```

However, when I try to call this checkwinner function again later on, the confetti doesn't work.  It only seems to work on one run through and not a second run through later. Can someone please explain why and offer a solution?

Comment: The second time you call checkWinner does it print TEST ?

Comment: The first time I run it, confetti falls and 'test' appears, the second time, confetti doesn't fall but 'test' appears, so it's definitely running through the confetti function but nothing appears on screen. Just to clarify, I never close the screen or stop the program running, just reset everything on screen, must be something to do with the view